# Removing a method call from the stack

Tags: java

suppose I have a game with a text interface. Now, when starting the game the player needs to tell the game their age.

```
public void getAge() {
    System.out.println("Please enter your age");
    int age;
    try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            age = sc.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("You made a mistake. Let's start this over!");
        getAge();
    }
    gameLoop(age);
}
```

Suppose the user makes 100 errors, and the method is called over and over again. Do the 100 calls stay on the call stack? Is there any way to remove them, perhaps by returning a value instead?

Is this a memory leak (although small)?

Anyway, I would like to hear your thoughts, on how this could be improved.

Comment: A loop instead of recursion would prevent additional calls to the function.

Comment: @twain249 Hmm, so one can nest a loop within a try/catch to manage exceptions within the same call?

Comment: Just put the loop outside of the `try {...} catch (...) {...}` blocks.

Comment: @twain249 Loops are fine etc... Still a valid question: does Java version XYZ support tail-call optimization yes/no? It might be easy to replace recursion by a loop in this case. It might be not entirely trivial in more complex cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a loop (Just pseudocode)

```
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
   try {
      // Get the age
      if (valid) { done = true; }
   }
   catch { // ...
       // Handle the exception make sure done is still false
   }
} // End while
```